# I have got 2 questions

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the sentences:

1. The bailer's on a jip (= the harvester, combine has got some troubles, stopped working?)
2. That's the whole harvest shot clean to buggery right there (?)

These come from **The Ferryman** a 2017 play by Jez Butterworth about a family in rural Northern Ireland.

Comment: Please tell us what book these sentences come from. You have been asked before to _give the source_ when asking the meaning of a sentence.

Comment: The book is called The Ferryman

Comment: ...and who wrote it?

Comment: Jezz Butterworth

Comment: More context as Kate says **and** a title that indicates the content of your question.

Comment: From the full OED: ***to give (a person) gyp:** (of a part of the body, a situation, a condition, etc.) to hurt (a person), to cause pain for; (hence) to cause trouble for, to irritate or distress.* It's probably the same word that's more often used in colloquial AmE to mean ***trick, con*** (verb and noun, spellings include ***jip*** AND ***gyp***), but in the cited context it's ***trouble*** (the bailer's ***on the blink, not working properly***).

Comment: (Butterworth is English, so it's quite natural for him to say that something's ***shot to buggery***, but that particular turn of phrase would probably appear strange to most Americans.)

Answer (score 1):

It was pointed out in the comments that jip is Irish slang for sperm or ejaculated semen, so an equivalent US phrase for the first sentence might be something like “The bailer is jacking off” or in non vulgar terms, “The bailer isn’t working”.  The second sentence is clear: the harvest was lost, typically this would be because of frost or rain or flooding, although drought or locust also be the cause.  The result of losing a harvest is somewhere between severe financial loss and death.

Comment: ... to "shoot to buggery" is a bit obscene expression, is not it? :-) I understand the meaning, but still there are nuances in translations... thank you./ In terms of the first question, the context is: The ground is still too wet. The bailer's on a jip.

Comment: I see it's a play set in Northern Ireland. I can't find any reference to the specific phrase 'on a jip' so we can only guess that it means broken down - and, yes, 'shot to buggery' is pretty crude language.

Comment: @Susa: yes, and for a farmer, loosing a harvest is well worth some obscenity.

Comment: You can say 'buggery' or 'buggered' pretty safely in the UK these days, especially if you aren't using it in the legal sense.

Comment: @jmoreno "loosing a harvest is well worth some obscenity" - yes, and losing it even more so.

Comment: @KateBunting -  'jip' is Irish slang for 'ejaculated semen' which fits with the other term, and the idea of sexual swearing to mean spoiled, ruined or broken (like 'the car's f***ked' or 'screwed').

Comment: I have also found "jip=to ejaculate", but was not able to find a connection with a bailer, now it is perfectly clear. Thank you.